# Function override error and abstract error after importing the contract

Tags: erc-721, function, abstract, override

*this a contract for erc721:
contract erc721{
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId);
event Approval(address indexed _owner,address indexed _approved, uint256 indexed _tokedId);

```
function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns(uint256);
```

*I am importing erc721 in my contract and using it in function with definition as below

function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns(uint256){
return ownerZombieCount[_owner];
}

I am getting function override error in 2nd contract and abstract error in erc721 contract. please help in solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried adding `override` to make it

```
function balanceOf(address _owner) external override view returns(uint256)
{ 
    return ownerZombieCount[_owner]; 
}
```